# Discord.py. Можно ли получать информацию о сообщении под которым нажата реакция?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Можно ли через ивент on_raw_reaction_add(payload) вытащить текст сообщения(embed) под которым была реакция?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению нет, вот всьо то что можна достать с [`payload`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.RawReactionActionEvent)

А еще можна просто посмотреть через команду:

```
@bot.command()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print(payload)#и просто нажмите на реакцию и вы увидите что можна достать с payload
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно ли как-то через другой ивент вытащить текст?